# Fingerprint scanner not working

Tags: drivers, lenovo, fingerprint-reader, ideapad, kali-linux-tools

My laptop is a Lenovo Ideapad s540 and I have installed Ubuntu 22.04.3 in it. My laptop comes with a fingerprint scanner and it was working when I was using Windows, but after shifting to Ubuntu my scanner is not working. I have tried numerous platforms and I didn't get anything specific to my PC.

The fingerprint driver on my PC is Bus 001 Device 002: ID 27c6:55b4 Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co., Ltd. Fingerprint Reader
Please give me steps if any.

Comment: What does `fprintd-enroll` return?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it looks like that scanner is not supported on Linux. The manufacturer has said they aren't going to provide Linux support (supposedly they said it in this thread, though I haven't paged through to find their response yet: https://developers.goodix.com/en/bbs/detail/3aa4b47f7c6f42bab61e661e2aa14c94?orderType=hot&&page=1), and no-one has successfully written a driver that works. You can see around four years of comments here, for example, where people were discussing efforts but don't seem to have succeeded: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libfprint/libfprint/-/issues/173